# Change binding syntax in AngularJs or Polymer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, polymer

I am using a **AngularJS** component inside the **Polymer** component

I have a problem when I am trying to binding data 1-way to AngularJS component

See the code below :

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id='application-wrapper'>
  <template>
    <h1>AngularJS</h1>
    <div ng-app='app' id="container">
      <div class="row" >
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <h2>Image manager : </h2>
                <file-manager-tile  objects="objects" mode={{modeEdit}}></file-manager-tile>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="clickHere($event)">Click Angular here <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
            <p>{{modeEdit}}</p>
      </div>            
    </div>
    <h1>Polymer</h1>
    <p>{{modeEdit}}</p>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" on-click="onPolymerClick">Click Polymer here <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'application-wrapper',
    properties: {
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.scopeSubtree(this.$.container, true);
    },
    onPolymerClick: function() {
        alert("Polymer");
    }
  });
</script>
<script>
angular.module('app',['xcomponent-widgets'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$filter,$timeout) {
        $scope.clickHere = function($event){
            alert("Angular");
        }

        $scope.objects = [
            { "_id": null,
                "binary": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/",
                "sequense": null,
                "angle": 0
            },
            { 
                "_id": null,
                "binary": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/",
                "sequense": null,
                "angle": 0
            }
            ,{ 
                "_id": null,
                "binary": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/",
                "sequense": null,
                "angle": 0
            }
        ];

        $scope.modeEdit = 'edit';

    });
</script>
```

in **file-manager-tile** directive , the binding *objects="objects"* work correctly,

But the *mode={{modeEdit}}* doesn't work, the value of *mode* inside **file-manager-tile** is *undefined*.

I think it because of confusing between binding syntax of **AngularJS** and **Polymer**

Is there any way to change the binding syntax of them ?

Thanks!

Added [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NUh2cs?p=preview)

Comment: Have you try this : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @JulCh suggesstion. I added the code

```
angular.module('app', ['widgets'])
  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('((');
   $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('))');
})
```

And changed:

```
 <file-manager-tile  objects="objects" mode=((modeEdit))></file-manager-tile>
```

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NUh2cs?p=preview)